# Suggest data container for array of arrays in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, data-containers

I need to put a `UITableViewCell` containing **3** `UILabel` and **1** `UIImage` into a `UITableView`.

What would be the best data container for this?

1. `NSArrays` in `NSMutableArray`?
2. `NSDictionarys` in `NSMutableArray`?

The **3** `UILabel` are not modifiable but the `UIImage` may be modified.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Give me a break. You all are picking on text legibility than solving the problem? Pencil pushers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the comments. I managed to figure it out.

In order to solve the above, I had a NSMutableArray that houses multiple NSMutableDictionaries.

Problem solved.